# Euler-Lagrange equation for squared integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

Can an Euler-Lagrange equation be derived for the following functional?

$$F[y'] = \int h(x) (y'(x))^4 dx - \big( \int h(x) (y'(x))^2 dx\big)^2.$$

Here $h(x)\geq 0$ and $\int h(x) dx = 1$.
Note, that the functional is not written as a single integral in this form. So my question is, how to solve this? Can it even be solved?

Comment: Hi quantumphilip. Welcome to Math.SE. Are there any boundary conditions?

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, no there are not!

Comment: Also: the prime seems irrelevant.

Comment: the prime indicates a derivative

Comment: Is $h$ non-negative? Is $h$ positive? Is $h$ integrable? What is the value of $\int \! dx~h(x)$?

Comment: $\int h(x) dx = 1$  and $h(x) \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

1. If we replace $z=y^{\prime}$ then OP's functional becomes
   $$\begin{align} F[z]~:=~&H_4[z]-H_2[z]^2, \cr 
   H_4[z]~:=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx~h(x) z(x)^4, \cr 
   H_2[z]~:=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx~h(x) z(x)^2, \cr
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx~h(x)~=~&1.
   \end{align}\tag{A}$$
2. The [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is
   $$ \frac{\delta F[z]}{\delta z(x)}~=~ 4h(x)z(x)(z(x)^2-H_2[z]). \tag{B}$$
   OP's sought-for equation is asking when the functional derivative (B) is zero.
3. Let us for simplicity additionally assume that

   1. $x\mapsto z(x)$ is continuous, and
   2. $h>0$ is positive (and leave the non-negative case $h\geq 0$ for the reader to work out).
4. Then one may show that the [stationary configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) are the constant configurations
   $$z(x)=c~\in~\mathbb{R}.\tag{C}$$
5. The 2nd functional derivative is
   $$ \frac{\delta^2 F[z]}{\delta z(x)\delta z(x^{\prime})}~=~ 4h(x)\delta(x\!-\!x^{\prime})(3z(x)^2-H_2[z])-8h(x)z(x)h(x^{\prime})z(x^{\prime}). \tag{D}$$
   Then
   $$ \left. \frac{\delta^2 F[z]}{\delta z(x)\delta z(x^{\prime})}\right|_{z=c}~=~ 8c^2h(x)(\delta(x\!-\!x^{\prime})-h(x^{\prime})). \tag{E}$$
6. One may show that the constant configurations are [saddle points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point). (The case $c=0$ requires a bit more work.)

Comment: Many thanks, this makes perfect sense to me.